# Как реализовать border-image в этом случае?

Tags: css3

Источник вопроса : https://toster.ru/q/504757#answers_list

Я всё сделал кроме маленького ньюанса, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я понимаю что нужен svg но может быть можно обойтись и без него ?

**Как реализовать border-image в этом случае?**
Это то что я уже сделал :

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ul{
  height:100px;
  background:url(http://st-gdefon.gallery.world/wallpapers_original/74533_gallery.world.jpg?9b30f88865a6ee068aa988b568d8492f);
  background-size:cover;
  transform:translate(0,100px);
  border-top:4px solid yellow;
  border-bottom:4px solid yellow;
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
ul li{
  margin-right:30px;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  line-height:100px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}
ul a{
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:1.6em;
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}
ul li:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  background:rgb(255,255,255);
  position:absolute;
  top:-40px; left:-30%;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom:4px solid yellow;
  border-right:4px solid yellow;
  visibility:hidden;
}
ul li:hover:after{
 visibility:visible; 
}

ul li:first-child:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-40px; left:-20px;
  z-index:200;
  border-top:40px solid red;
  border-left:40px solid transparent;
  border-right:40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:40px solid transparent;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Похожий: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770441/%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: @VladSpirin какой же он похожий ? ни какого сходства ...

Answer (score 0):

Хоть я и опоздал...

```css
body {padding:100px}
.block {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg);
}

.block:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:-55px;
  display:block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```